# Can an app find out if the Android phone it's running on supports Bluetooth 4.3 privacy extensions?

Tags: bluetooth, privacy

I need to find out if the phone my app is running on supports the [BT 4.2 bluetooth privacy extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_4.2). If so, it will tell a BT connected device to do the same, if not it will not enable it.

Is there a way to find out by means of a script if the underlying Android supports the privacy extensions?

My assumption here is, based on two low cost phones, that for some mobile phones BT4.2 compatibility is claimed, yet enabling it on the slave device voids the communication with the device.

Comment: If you want to get this information from within your app this is more a question for https://stackoverflow.com as app-development is off-topic here. Typically an answer here would involve `adb`or something like that which is not accessible from within an app.

Comment: OP has posted [the same question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66347527/2821954) for app development/programming question, in case anyone is interested.

Comment: OP has taken up the excellent advice from @Robert in doing so and feels delighted to receive such heart felt attention for his quest in seeking the Bluetruth.